# Have Narrow Distribution - Need Standard Distribution

Tags: r, distributions, data-transformation

I am building a model in R using GLM based on this predictor variable.  As you can see, the data is concentrated in the center of the distribution, and then falls off sharply.  Is there a transformation to make this distribution wider?

Another option I'm considering is to weight the data points on the ends, using the weights argument in GLM.  Is there any reason why that would be a bad idea?

[image]

Comment: Why do you want a "wider" distribution of the predicor variable ?

Comment: Because I am running a logistic regression with this data used as a predictor variable.  Logistic regression assumes a standard distribution.  You can see in the histogram above it is not a standard distribution.  All of the data is concentrated in the center, than tails off too quickly to be a standard distribution.

Comment: "*Logistic regression assumes a standard distribution*" : where have you seen such a thing ?

Comment: Oh you're right, my mistake.  In the above histogram you can see I did a transformation and took the sqrt().  This is because without that transformation, there is a long tail to the right.  Am I correct that a skew like that could ruin the results of a logistic distribution?

Comment: There's no expectation about the shape of the distribution of a predictor. What you would would consider first for a transformation is whether it would make the relationship between the linear predictor and the transformed mean response more nearly linear. A long tail may have issues with having to estimate a relationship where there's little data, but that's not really about "ruining the results".